# DCEF show html in browser

Tags: html, delphi, chromium-embedded

I'm using DCEF (Delphi Chromium Embedded) in a Delphi project, I have the following question:
how can I show an html page generated by code in TChromium browser component ?

Comment: From string e.g. `Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString('<your HTML>', 'localhost');`.

Comment: Ok, working. Thank You.